# Does RabbitTemplate.send() guarantee the delivery of messages to RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Using Spring AMQP, when the call to the method `rabbitTemplate.send(message)`  returns (from org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate class), can we be sure that the message has been delivered and replicated on the RabbitMQ cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. AMQP is an asynchronous protocol. To guarantee delivery you need to use [Publisher Confirms and Returns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#template-confirms) - and even then, the confirmation (or return) comes back on another thread.

Comment: @Gary Russel, just out of curiosity, if I use a transacted channel, when I commit, if such commit succeeds, can I be certain the message was delivered? My understanding is that that holds, however, if it fails, there is no guarantee of full rollback (i.e. an exchange may have succeeded passing the message to some but no all queues). Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: It's generally best to ask a new question rather than adding questions in comments. The answer is that, even with a non-routable message and `mandatory`, the `commit` succeeds and the returned message comes back asynchronously (after the commit). I don't know the behavior with partial delivery but the documentation says "`In RabbitMQ the tx.commit-ok indicates that all transaction effects are visible...broker has accepted responsibility...`". You should ask questions about RabbitMQ internals on the `rabbitmq-users` Google group, which is where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out.

Comment: The commit fails if you publish to a non-existent exchange.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE: This is not correct answer. Please see the answer of @GaryRussell**

**If you mean the only communication between publisher and RabbitMQ**
then yes. You don't have to do anything other than that to ensure message storing and replication is part of RabbitMQ work.

**Please remember to [catch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#send-org.springframework.amqp.core.Message-) the `AmqpException` if there is any problem happen to send message!**

Comment: @GaryRussell I assumed Sébastien mean the communication between publisher and only the RabbitMQ. But if he means the subscriber then this is not correct.

Comment: No; even on the publisher side there is no guarantee that the message has been secured in the destination queue(s) when the `send()` method exits. His question was `can we be sure that the message has been delivered and replicated on the RabbitMQ cluster?` and the answer is a resounding NO - see my answer.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your answer. Im updating my answer to indicate your answer @GaryRussell

Comment: Yes I mean between the publisher and RabbitMQ (Rabbit exchange publication). My tests confirm that there's no guarantee of delivery. I will try Publisher Confirms and Returns pattern, which Gary mentioned.